# Can I display JSON Data with an SQL Query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, json, database

**Can I display JSON Data with an SQL Query?**

The segment below is my current JSON data:

```
[
   {
      "id":"BKU0000007",
      "judul":"jsjsj",
      "no_isbn":"ssksk",
      "penulis":"jsjsj",
      "penerbit":"iieie",
      "tahun_terbit":"2011",
      "halaman":"202",
      "berat":"220",
      "cover":"20202",
      "dimensi":"0202",
      "kategori":"Horor",
      "bahasa":"2020",
      "stok":"22020",
      "gambar":"BKU0000007.jpeg",
      "harga":"333",
      "sinopsis":"0202022"
   },
   {
      "id":"BKU0000006",
      "judul":"sshhs",
      "no_isbn":"3i3i3i",
      "penulis":"ssiis",
      "penerbit":"oo3o3",
      "tahun_terbit":"2009",
      "halaman":"20",
      "berat":"10000",
      "cover":"alks",
      "dimensi":"20x30",
      "kategori":"",
      "bahasa":"skks",
      "stok":"20",
      "gambar":"BKU0000006.jpeg",
      "harga":"29999",
      "sinopsis":"skkssk"
   }
]

    [
       {
          "id":"BKU0000007",
          "judul":"jsjsj",
          "no_isbn":"ssksk",
          "penulis":"jsjsj",
          "penerbit":"iieie",
          "tahun_terbit":"2011",
          "halaman":"202",
          "berat":"220",
          "cover":"20202",
          "dimensi":"0202",
          "kategori":"Horor",
          "bahasa":"2020",
          "stok":"22020",
          "gambar":"BKU0000007.jpeg",
          "harga":"333",
          "sinopsis":"0202022"
       },
       {
          "id":"BKU0000006",
          "judul":"sshhs",
          "no_isbn":"3i3i3i",
          "penulis":"ssiis",
          "penerbit":"oo3o3",
          "tahun_terbit":"2009",
          "halaman":"20",
          "berat":"10000",
          "cover":"alks",
          "dimensi":"20x30",
          "kategori":"",
          "bahasa":"skks",
          "stok":"20",
          "gambar":"BKU0000006.jpeg",
          "harga":"29999",
          "sinopsis":"skkssk"
       }
    ]
```

I would like to generate this data using an SQL query such as:

SELECT * FROM data etc...

**How can I accomplish this task? Can someone please guide me through this?**

Thank you for your time and patience in resolving this matter.

Comment: Which database mysql/postgresql/.. ?

Comment: my database is mysql @Avezan

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-shell-json-output.html

Comment: is it possible if i display data from json file using sql query? @Avezan

Comment: using javascript?

Comment: yes using javascript @Avezan

Comment: `show this data` - where?

Comment: thats json data i mean @JaromandaX

Comment: yes, but where do you want to "show" it, or "display" it - you haven't mentioned that. What is the reason for "show"ing the data

Comment: i want show it in html tags uaing javascript @JaromandaX

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest something like below:

a) you need to use ObjectMapper object

b) call writeValueAsString(object) of ObjectMapper object

c) To use ObjectMapper you need to have jackson core, jackson annotation,jackson databind jar in your classpath

Sample example:
   I create Example class to simulate your solution-code is as below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

class Example{
    int id;
    String name;

    public Example(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        List<List<Example>> list=new ArrayList<List<Example>>();

        List<Example> exampleList1=new ArrayList<>();
        exampleList1.add(new Example(1,"A"));
        list.add(exampleList1);

        List<Example> exampleList2=new ArrayList<>();
        exampleList2.add(new Example(1,"B"));
        list.add(exampleList2);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        String writeValueAsString = mapper.writeValueAsString(list);        
        System.out.println(writeValueAsString);
    }

}
```

Output:

[[{"id":1,"name":"A"}],[{"id":1,"name":"B"}]]

You replace your properties with Example class.

(If you have dao code then you need to prepare list of list of example object from dao layer after calling sql query and get result)

Hope you got the idea!!